# Tensorflow 2.0 how to export predictions and training-mode from Keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, export, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a model sub-classed from tf.keras.model . I have write a call -and predict methods. when I export the model it seems that only the output from call method is serialized. The simple code to illustrate the problem is below

```
class SimpleModel(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self):
    super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()

    self.layer1 = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
    self.layer2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
    self.layer3 = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

def call(self, x, training=False):

    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    if training:
        x = self.dropout(x)
    return self.layer3(x)

def predict(self, x):

    return tf.argmax(self(x))

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
           'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

model = SimpleModel()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

model.save('tf_test', save_format='tf')
```

When I inspect the saved model using the saved-model-cli the output is as below

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input_1'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_UINT8
      shape: (-1, 28, 28)
      name: serving_default_input_1:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['output_1'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 10)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

The output is exactly same without the predict method. So how can I get the prediction tensor included in the serialization and does the training mode need to be serialized. In tensorflow 1.x I can simply save the prediction tensor and training mode tensor using the following line of code

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, 'tf_test', inputs={"x": x, "mode": training_mode}, outputs={"predictions": predictions})
```

Comment: Shouldn't `argmax` operation be over the last `axis` (`axis=-1`)? I Suppose you would like the predictions to be numbers ranging from 0 to 9, so a vector of size `(batch,)`, right?

Comment: Yes one should specify the axis in argmax function. That is fixed now in the answer @SzymonMaszke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the solution to the export problem from the tensorflow documentation [Using save model format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) section *Exporting custom models*. The solution is to use tf.Module instead tf.keras.Model and use the tf.function annotation at the top of the function one wants to import. The working code is illustrated below

```
class SimpleModel(tf.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()

    self.layer1 = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
    self.layer2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
    self.layer3 = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

def __call__(self, x, training=False):

    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    # if training:
    #     x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    return x

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, 28, 28], tf.float32)])
def predict(self, x):

    return tf.argmax(self(x), axis=1)


def loss(m, x, y):
    logits = m(x, True)
    return tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(y, 10), (y.size, 10)), logits)


def grad(m, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    lv = loss(m, x, y)
    return lv, tape.gradient(lv, m.trainable_variables)


fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = 
fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
           'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

model = SimpleModel()

# model.compile(optimizer='adam',
#               loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
#               metrics=['accuracy'])
#
# model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

epochs = 100
batch_size = 1000
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-5)

for epoch in range(epochs):

    costs = []
    for k in range(int(train_images.shape[0] / batch_size)):
        start_index = k * batch_size
        end_index = (k + 1) * batch_size
        batch_x, batch_y = train_images[start_index:end_index, :, :], 
        train_labels[start_index:end_index]

        loss_value, grads = grad(model, batch_x, np.reshape(batch_y, (1000, 1)))
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        costs.append(loss_value.numpy())
    print("epoch %d of %d, cost %f" % (epoch, 10, np.mean(costs)))

signatures = {"serving_default": model.predict}

tf.saved_model.save(model, 'tf_test', signatures)
```

No the output of the saved_model_cli is

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['x'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 28, 28)
    name: serving_default_x:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['output_0'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_INT64
    shape: (-1)
    name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

which corresponds to the output of predict method outputting single label